# Separating stubs from assertions in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, bdd, rspec2

I'm using rspec and the rspec mocks library for stubbing/mocking, but I'm starting to think that the line between stubbing out a method and asserting how it's been used is blurred. In my tests I'll often write something like:

```
before(:each) do
  subject.should_receive(:sum).once.with([1, 2, 3]).and_return(6)
end

it("should do something that relies on sum") do
  subject.call_something([1, 2, 3]).should == 24
end
```

But what are my assertions? That `call_something([1, 2, 3])`:

- Returns `24`
- Calls `sum([1, 2, 3])` during it's execution

However, there is only one `it` block - the other assertion is hidden away in the stub definition. To put it another way, **my stub is also my assertion**. Wouldn't it be much clearer to separate the two, and put an explicit assertion in for how the stubbed method was called:

```
before(:each) do
  # set up what my stub should return for a given input
  subject.may_receive(:sum).with([1, 2, 3]).and_return(6)
end

# assert how my stub was actually called
it("should have called sum with 1, 2, 3") do
  # this is pseudo-rspec
  subject.call_something([1, 2, 3]).should have_called(:sum).on(subject).once.with([1, 2, 3])
end
it("should do something that relies on sum") do
  subject.call_something([1, 2, 3]).should == 24
end
```

This way it's very clear what I'm asserting because my stub definitions and assertions have been separated. I can setup my test at the top, and then check it's behaviour at the bottom, without mixing the two.

So, my question is whether there's a way of doing this? Most mocking frameworks work in the same way as rspec-mocks, and define the contract for how a stub method is used along with the expected behaviour, and then automagically check the assertion at the end.

My point is a conceptual one about how BDD works, and might be a bit subtle. Let me know I need to clarify it further!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. `should_receive` *is* an assertion (more accurately it is an *expectation*) and should not go in a `before` block. If you need the stubbing side-effect of `should_receive`, then stub separately in your `before`:

```
before do
  subject.stub(:sum).and_return(6)
end

it "should do something that relies on sum" do
  subject.should_receive(:sum).once.with([1, 2, 3]).and_return(6)
  subject.call_something([1, 2, 3]).should == 24
end
```

This keeps the stubbing and expectation separate and where they belong.

Comment: That looks good.But what if I need to call `sum` multiple times with different arguments and get different results each time? (That's why I've traditionally avoided using stub)

Comment: If the return value of a `stub` changes then the test should likely be in a different `context` block, in which case you can use `let`s to reduce duplication of `before` blocks.